# why doesn't first function return 0 ? Tell me differense between them

Tags: javascript

first function:

```js
function filter_list(l) {
  return l.filter(x => {
    if (x >= 0) {
      return x
    }
  })
}
console.log(filter_list([1, 'a', 'b', 0, 15]));
```

> returns [1, 15]

```js
function filter_list(l) {
  return l.filter(x => x >= 0)
}
console.log(filter_list([1, 'a', 'b', 0, 15]));
```

> returns [1, 0, 15]

Comment: `filter` accepts a predicate - it should return `true` or `false`. However, if you return zero, that coerces to `false`, hence it's filtered out.

Comment: or, in other words, `0` is *falsey*

Answer (score 0):

The first function is not including the `0` in the final result array, as you are returning `x` itself when the expression in the`if` is satisfied:

```
if(x >= 0) {
   //When x is 0, the filter predicate becomes Falsy
   return x
}
```

When `x` is `0` it is a *Falsy* value hence filter skips on that value of `x`.

In the second case `x >= 0` is the return value, so when `x` is `0` the expression `x >= 0` becomes a boolean `true` and hence that value of `x` is included in the final result.